# Javascript how to reproduce GLSL floating point matrix operation on CPU Uint8array

Tags: javascript, floating-point, glsl, webgl, typed-arrays

I have some data in a `Uint8array`, ( a list of 3d x,y,z coordinates). I need to perform some floating point operations on. (matrix rotation transform multiplication) on this 3d vectors. I am using the http://glmatrix.net/ library for the calculations.

The data is coming from a 3rd party API that packages it as `Uint8Array` The vertex data is formatted in sets of 8 `[x,y,z,w,r,g,b,a]`

Up until now, I have been performing this operation on the GPU, passing this `Uint8array` and the rotation matrix to GLSL. I am moving the operation to a CPU based script that is executed offline.

**Update** Another piece of the equation. The offline script is a node.js CLI script that writes the final buffer to stdout and eventually to a file using the unix `>` operator. I then load this in the final app and wrap the `arrayBuffer` with a `typedArray` constructor.

When executed in GLSL, the operation looks like:

`matrix * vec4(vert.x, vert.y, vert.z, 1.0)`

and my results look like:
[image]

Now on the CPU My current code attempt is:

```
  const vertData = getVertDataUint8();
  const rotation = mat4.fromRotation(mat4.identity([]), -Math.PI/2, [1,0,0]);
  var i = 0;
  while(i<vertData.length){
    const rotatedVerts = vec4.transformMat4([],
                                            vec4.clone([vertData[i],vertData[i+1],vertData[i+2], 1]),
                                            rotation);

    vertData[i] = rotatedVerts[0];
    vertData[i+1] = rotatedVerts[1];
    vertData[i+2] = rotatedVerts[2];
    i+=8;
  }
```

and my results look like:
[image]

I noticed that when re assigning the values to the vertData, specifically negative values they were being cast as ints. example `-10` ~= `246`

you can reproduce in a browser console with:

```
var u = new Uint8Array(1)
undefined
u[0] = -10
-10
u[0]
246
```

I have tried converting the `Uint8Array` into a `Float32Array` by wrapping it in the `Float32Array` constructor and using `Float32Array.from` but it seems to produce the same results.

Comment: First of all: Please use the `Float32Array` for vertex data. And why are you using `i+=8;`? Your UInt8Array should be looking like this: `[X1,Y1,Z1,...]` or `[X1,Y1,Z1,W1,...]` so with the `i+=8` you are skipping at least every second vert.

Comment: @Bellian I should add that the vertex data comes to from a 3rd party source that is not easily updatable. Can I convert the `Uint8Array` to `Float32Array`, Additionally the vertex format is actually sets of 8 attributes [x,y,z,w,r,g,b,a] so iterating in steps of 8 is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Consider using the `Float32Array` for your vertex information. Otherwise there can be massive problems. Or at least use non unsigned data formats.

Now your Problem:

Since `Uint8Array` is a unsigned data format it will only save positive 8-bit values. All negative values will be interpreted as positives (`10000000` as signed integer is `-128` but as unsigned it is `128`)

But i guess the real problem is another one.
From the code i assume that you are saving the vertex information like this:

`[X1,Y1,Z1,...]` or `[X1,Y1,Z1,W1,...]`

Your loop will iterate over the array in steps of 8 since `i+=8;`. 
Therefore at least every second vertex will be skipped in your script.

Comment: I updated the question and replied to your original comment on the vertex data format

Comment: For the record. I had to use the `.from` method to convert the data `const vertData = Float32Array.from(getVertDataUint8());`  and when writing to disk I had to use `process.stdout.write(Buffer.from(vertData.buffer));`